# Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'D:\...\src' - reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, npm

I have installed **jquery 1.9.1** via npm command. After installation got completed i am getting the below error while i build my **reactjs** application.

```
> webapp-react@0.1.0 build D:\Local_Instance\src\main\webapp-react
> react-scripts build
```

> Creating an optimized production build...
>   Failed to compile.
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'D:\Local_Instance\src\main\webapp-react\src'

Please find my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "webapp-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {

   "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
   "bson-objectid": "^1.1.5",
   "jquery": "^1.9.1",
   "moment": "^2.18.1",
   "react": "^15.6.1",
   "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
 "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"homepage": "."
}
```

index.js file where i required to use `jquery`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';


global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
ReactDOM.render(<App view="DemoApp" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Can you try `npm install` once here?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - packages should go under `node_modules` rite..? i have installed other packages under `node-modules` only.

Comment: That's right bro. But how did you install the packages?

Comment: from command prompt i used this command to install `D:\Local_Instance\src\main\webapp-react>npm install jquery@1.9.1`

Comment: Seems to be the right command. `:)`

Comment: can you show the code where you require/import jquery

Comment: Added with index.js file., where am expecting `jquery`

Comment: What do you need jQuery for when using React?